ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ fails on 2 ULPs
According to Google Test's documentation about floating point comparison, EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ and ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ verify that the two double values val1 and val2 are approximately equal, to within 4 ULPs (Units in the Last Place) from each other.
The following code example, however, fails the test even though the difference in the two doubles occur in 2 ULPs.
TEST(Foo, doubles_match)
{
   ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ(0.62469504755442462, 0.62469504755442407);
}

Results:
error: Expected equality of these values:
0.62469504755442462
0.62469504755442407

What am I missing?

The difference between 0.6246950475544246206283105493639595806598663330078125 and
0.62469504755442406551679823678568936884403228759765625 is
0.00000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, which is 5 ULPs.  You can count the number of steps needed using std::nextafter.  Unless I'm on a different page for what ULPs means in this context.

Those are text representations of floating-point values. It is not self-evident that the corresponding floating-point values differ by 2 ULPs. Subtract the floating-point values and see what the difference is. Note that ULP refers to the internal representations (typically binary) of the values, not to the text that was converted to the values.

Or better put them into 10 base convert where it is obvious that they differ by 5 ULP. Output in FP hexadecimal a format is also helpful for checking exact mantissa values (or transferring them between programs reliably as text).

Thank you for your responses! I am aware of the IEEE standardization on double precision, whereby the precision is determined by ~52 bits (1 sign + 11 exponent + ~52 precision). I was thinking this might have been the reason, but it also backfired because the difference in the numbers for the full extent of the precision range is more than 5 ULPs. Technically, it is 37 ULPs. Please see this code example: https://rextester.com/OIUA56796. Also, according to the compiler explorer, I think that the numbers are stringified: https://godbolt.org/z/EYb6T8cjT

The numbers mentioned in the question are 5 ULPs apart (considering binary 64-bit IEEE-754 numbers). You can verify this with this program:
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>
#include <print>

int main() {
    const std::uint64_t a = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(0.62469504755442462);
    const std::uint64_t b = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(0.62469504755442407);
    std::print("{:016x}\n", a);
    std::print("{:016x}\n", b);
    std::print("diff: {}\n", a - b);
}

It outputs:
3fe3fd8077e7057a
3fe3fd8077e70575
diff: 5


Related note: I'm not sure I like the design of this comparison function. Why 4 ULPs? Why is it a good value? In my opinion, it should have the maximum allowed difference as an input parameter. There can be calculations where 4 ULP is too small. The proper way of doing this is follow the steps of the calculation, knowing which steps introduce errors, and design the allowed ULP difference accordingly.

(in reply to comment) Isn't there an ASSERT_NEAR macro for that?

@BenVoigt: I'm not familiar with google test, but yes, it seems it has this. It uses an absolute value for difference (so it's not ULP based). I think this version is much better if one pays attention to determine the absolute error properly (not just writes some ad-hoc epsilon value there, like the 4 ULP)

@geza: I also don't fully grasp the design decision behind 4 ULPs. If anything, ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ should verify whether or not two doubles have exactly the same digits in the full range of precision, nevermind the improbability of that happening if the doubles are results of computations, and use ASSERT_NEAR with an epsilon for everything else.

@ConstantinosGlynos: for exact comparison, == is already available.

@ConstantinosGlynos The operator strict == already exists for FP but it is almost useless for checking double precision or FP arithmetic for strict equality since rounding error is ubiquitous in any non-trivial numerical algorithm. Accepting +/- 2ULP or 4ULP as almost equal and say +/-16 ULP as nearly equal allows enough slack that most decent algorithms will pass on any platform. If you use strict == you will chase your own tail. It almost never works for floating point arithmetic in the way that beginners expect. If you really care you histogram on ULP error.

@ConstantinosGlynos There is no such thing as full range of precision in floating point numbers. You can generally expect that converting from decimal representation to double and then back to decimal with the same number of significant digits (at most 15-17) should give you the same number, but that's about it - this "precision" cannot say anything about calculation precision or actual number stored. About 4 ULPs: it's good enough to allow some calculations, where == fails: https://godbolt.org/z/dfsq35517. Whether it's good enough for your use case, we can't tell.
